# "Which" Relative Clause--"Which", "Of Which", or what?

Tags: adjectives, relative-clauses, clauses

I'm struggling with a relative 'which' clause right now; I'm hoping to structure it a certain way, but while I feel like I've read it that way before, I'm just not sure if it's correct and I can't find any examples of that construction. Here's the sentence in question (and the clause in bold):

> I do not observe any supposed distinction between the soul and the mind, **the latter which I consider little more than a reductive account of the former**.

My goal is to communicate this without constructing an independent clause:

> I do not observe any supposed distinction between the soul and the mind; I consider the latter little more than a reductive account of the former.

The real snag is that I would use something like,

> I do not observe any supposed distinction between the soul and the mind, which I consider little more than a reductive account of the former.

but I'm not fond of using 'the former' without clarifying the subject of the relative clause with 'the latter' (the way I read it, 'which' could, in the above version, refer to 'any supposed distinction').

How, if at all, should I revise the first version of my sentence?

Would something like,

> I do not observe any supposed distinction between the soul and the mind, the latter **of** which I consider little more than a reductive account of the former.

be correct?

Comment: I agree with the observation about your first example; did you write this?  Please do take a moment to [tour] the site, read the [FAQ], and enjoy the research.

Comment: Your third rewriting is fine, you don't need 'former' anywhere because 'of which' makes clear what the former and latter are. It's the same as dealing with a longer list, for example "These yogurts come in strawberry, vanilla, cherry and raspberry flavours of which I prefer the last one"

Comment: Aside from style and subjective opinion, it's not clear why you think there's a problem with the original sentence. Based on the final suggestion, are you asking if a preposition is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Subject to others’ opinions, I feel your concluding version to be clear, unambiguous, grammatical and correct. Another way of achieving your aim might be ... *and the mind, the latter being little more than a reductive account of the former* or *... the mind, it being little more ...*

Comment: "I do not observe any supposed distinction between the soul and the mind, which I consider little more than a reductive account of the soul." would be better than "...the former" because it's clearer what is being referred to, and repeating "soul" emphasises the contrast.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need either "which" or "of which".

"The latter" alone is quite sufficient as it is as refers to the second of two.

I do not observe any supposed distinction between the soul and the mind; *[semicolon]* the latter <s>[of] which</s> I consider little more than a reductive account of the former.